# disabling grid after reloading the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

using file uploader i am able to upload to gridview but i want to hide the grid  when i refreshes the page using reload this page in the browser and againg display the grid when the user selects the file using file uploader how can i do this

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    UploadStatusLabel.Text = "";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to take that grid in panel and on you page load event do

```
pnl.visible=false;
```

it worked for me